# len() of a 2D array (PYTHON) is not coming correctly

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Refer to the below simple code snippet. gets inputs for 2d Array and prints the size of it

```
def prefix_sum_Rish():
    rows = int(input("type number of rows"))
    columns = int(input("type number of columns"))
    matrix = [[]]
    #getting input from console
    for i in range(rows):
        temp = []
        for j in range(columns):
            x = int(input("number please"))
            temp.append(x)
        matrix.append(temp)

    print("size of matrix" + str(len(matrix)))
prefix_sum_Rish()
```

The input given and the output is

```
    type number of rows3
    type number of columns3
    number please1
    number please2
    number please3
    number please4
    number please5
    number please6
    number please7
    number please8
    number please9
    size of matrix4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

len(matrix) returns 4 while it should be 3.
If I give the number of rows as 2, then len(matrix) returns 3. Always len(matrix) gives rows + 1.
Any idea why it is coming up like that?

Comment: In your own words, what do you think the length of `matrix` should be *before* you start appending rows? According to Python, what *is* that actual length? Do you understand why Python gives and answer that it does? Also, these are *not* arrays (we call them *lists*) and they are *not* "2d" just because you nest them. If you want actual *rectangular* storage (what people normally mean by a 2d array, where all rows are forced to be the same length, and the implementation doesn't have to track each row separately) then you need a third-party library.

Comment: Well 1 + 3 = 4.

Comment: To elaborate on Kelly's comment: Your `matrix = [[]]` already contains one element to begin with: an empty list `[]`. Then you add three lists to that in your loop. 1 + 3 = 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you initialize your matrix with empty array.

So in the end you have a matrix like this:

```
mat = [[], [1,2], [3,4]]
```

So the final len is one more than expected